# Problemas con el scrollY de la datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables, datatable

Alguien me puede ayudar con este error quiero ponerle el `scrollY` cuando se elije mostrar mas de 10 registros

```js
var table = $('#tblDistribucionZonas').DataTable({
  dom: 'lBfrtip',
  pageLength: 10,
  buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
  ],
  language: {
    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
    "infoPostFix": "",
    "thousands": ",",
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar:",
    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
    "paginate": {
      "first": "Primero",
      "last": "Ultimo",
      "next": "Siguiente",
      "previous": "Anterior"
    }
  }
});
$("select[name=tblDistribucionZonas_length]").on("change", function() {
  var valor_seleccionado = $(this).val();
  if (valor_seleccionado > 10) {
    $('#tblDistribucionZonas').dataTable({
      'sScrollY': 100
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.table-responsive {
  border: 0px;
}

.table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="tblDistribucionZonas">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Puesto en el top</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Zona</th>
        <th>Venta</th>
        <th>Ingreso</th>
        <th>Iva</th>
        <th>Descuento</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero necesitas inicializar el `scrollY` con algun valor.  Luego para ajustarlo necesitas cambiar el `height` con css asi:

```js
var table = $('#tblDistribucionZonas').DataTable({
  dom: 'lBfrtip',
  pageLength: 10,
  buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
  ],
  scrollY: "350px",
  language: {
    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
    "infoPostFix": "",
    "thousands": ",",
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar:",
    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
    "paginate": {
      "first": "Primero",
      "last": "Ultimo",
      "next": "Siguiente",
      "previous": "Anterior"
    }
  }
});
$("select[name=tblDistribucionZonas_length]").on("change", function() {
  var valor_seleccionado = $(this).val();
  if (valor_seleccionado > 10) {
    $('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('height', 450);    
  }
});
```

```css
.table-responsive {
  border: 0px;
}

.table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="tblDistribucionZonas">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Puesto en el top</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Zona</th>
        <th>Venta</th>
        <th>Ingreso</th>
        <th>Iva</th>
        <th>Descuento</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: eso es lo que quiero evitar iniciar el scroll pero gracias